# Вывод всех строк

Tags: строки, php, mysql

Делаю список юзеров в форме таблицы, и столкнулся с тем, что

```
mysqli_fetch_array
```

разбивает только одну строку (первую).

Как задаю:

```
  $users = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users`");
  $users_count = mysqli_num_rows($users);
  $users_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($users);
```

Как пробовал выводить:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$users_count; $i++) {
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>$users_rows[id][$i]</td>
        <td>$users_rows[Login][$i]</td>
        <td>$users_rows[Email][$i]</td>
        <td>$users_rows[Active_On][$i]</td>
        <td>$users_rows[Active_Off][$i]</td>
        <td>$users_rows[Company][$i]</td>
    </tr>";
    } // будет выдавать первую строку со значениями $i в виде текста
```

Как правильно вывести все строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) вытаскивает из результата только одну строку. Чтобы вытащить следующие нужно повторно вызвать `mysqli_fetch_array`. Просто внесите строку

```
$users_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($users);
```

внутрь цикла.

Comment: а ей не надо указывать какую номером строку вытаскивать?

Comment: Нет. При каждом вызове она берёт следующую строку из выборки. Если строки в выборке заканчиваются, она начинает возвращать NULL.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $users = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users`");

  while($users_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($users)){
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$users_rows[id][$i]</td>
            <td>$users_rows[Login][$i]</td>
            <td>$users_rows[Email][$i]</td>
            <td>$users_rows[Active_On][$i]</td>
            <td>$users_rows[Active_Off][$i]</td>
            <td>$users_rows[Company][$i]</td>
        </tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Почитайте](http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles) все же внимательно о циклах в php и постарайтесь определить какой использовать и в каком случае!

Используйте функцию `print_r($var)` для того чтобы видеть всю структуру данных.

*notice:* в вашем случае будет пригодным цикл `while`

```
while($users_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($users))
{
//...
}
```